# How can I fill in a value from one TextBox to another TextBox in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to see how I would type something in 1 textbox and once I leave that box the second textbox gets filled in.

I have

```
<InputNumber Value="vm.Value1" ValueChanged="ChangedMethod"/>
<InputNumber @bind-Value= "vm.Value2" />

@code {
   private void ChangeMethod(){
       // do stuff here

   }
}
```

Now I am not sure I think I got to pass a parameter in the "ChangeMethod" but I don't know what or how. Is it a "decimal" or is it "ChangeEventArgs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's various ways this can be done.

### `Value` & `ValueChanged`

This method requires you to define the `TValue` and the `ValueExpression` for the type of the property, and the `TValue` that you define here is what gets passed to the `ValueChanged` handler method as a parameter.
It also requires you to set the property of the `Value` manually in the handler method.

```
<InputNumber Value="vm.Value1" ValueChanged="UpdateValues" TValue="int" ValueExpression="@( () => vm.Value1)"/>
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value2" />

@code {
    private void UpdateValues(int value)
    {
        vm.Value1 = value;
        vm.Value2 = value;
    }
}
```

### `@onblur`

##### *Note:* This event fires when the component loses focus, even if the value is never changed.

Even clicking in and out of an input will fire this event. It can be used alongside the `@bind-Value` directive or the `Value` `ValueChanged` longform. If using the `@bind` directive the `ValueExpression` and `TValue` do not need to be declared. The parameter that gets passed to the handler method is `FocusEventArgs` so you will have to get the changed value from the model itself.

```
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value1" @onblur="UpdateWithBind"/>
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value2" />

@code {
    private void UpdateWithBlur(FocusEventArgs args)
    {
        vm.Value2 = vm.Value1;
    }
}
```

## Additonal methods

---

### `@oninput`

##### *Note:* This fires on each input

The handler method defined using this directive gets passed the `ChangeEventArgs` that contains the new input value. The difference between this and the others is that it will trigger the method on each input.

```
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value1" @oninput="UpdateOnInput" />
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value2" />

@code {
    private void UpdateOnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        int value = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        vm.Value2 = value;
    }
}
```

### Property with custom getter and setter

You could also use a custom property getter and setter to achieve this, this allows the use of the auto binding `@bind-Value`. This creates simplicity in the component, but adds complexity to the class and separating component UI logic to a class would probably not be a good idea.

```
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value1" />
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value2" />

@code {
    MyClass vm = new();
    public class MyClass
    {
        private int _value1;
        public int Value1 
        { 
            get { return _value1; }
            set 
            {
                _value1 = value;
                Value2 = value;
            }
        }
        public int Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

## .NET 7+

### `@bind-after`

This directive does not pass any parameters and is used for methods that you want to call after the value has been set.

```
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value1" @bind-Value:after="UpdateWithAfter"/>
<InputNumber @bind-Value="vm.Value2" />

@code {
    private void UpdateWithAfter(){
        vm.Value2 = vm.Value1;
    }
}
```

[Demo snippet with the examples](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkGdkDlGVfLGogka)

Comment: Cool, I figured it also with ValueChanged though it is good to see as I was not sure if I got it right or not. I believe I was able to do it without the TValue though.

Also what the advantage/disadvantaged to do ValueChanges vs  onblur? I like how .net7 is doing it but I am stuck using .net6

I guess if I want it to show right away after each time I type I would use @oninput but I don't think I need that for my needs.

Comment: With Value and ValueChanged you can decide how to set the components `Value` any way you want, **using the user input**  and the other has no access to the user input.

Comment: **for example** you want to bind the user inputs to a string property  https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYmxaZlwWbjWxApH

Comment: And with onBlur that would not be the case? It looks almost the same expect you doing it through a change event and not passing in the value.

Comment: Actually yea, it could be done using `@onblur` as well, I guess the two differences between them are that `@onblur` can be used with a `@bind` and it will fire even if you just click on the input and click out of it., even if the value was never changed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand you, but here's some examples that show you how.

Example 1 sets up the binding manually.  I use `ChangeMethod` to set bot values.

Examples 2 shows the auto binding.

Example 3 shows auto binding and using the `after` bind to update the other value.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<InputNumber class="form-control" TValue="int" Value="vm.Value1" ValueChanged="ChangeMethod" ValueExpression="() => vm.Value1" />
<InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="vm.Value2" />
<InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value="vm.Value1" @bind-Value:after="AfterMethod" />

@code {
    private Model vm = new();

    private void ChangeMethod(int value)
    {
        vm.Value1 = value;
        vm.Value2 = value;
    }

    private void AfterMethod()
    {
        vm.Value2 = vm.Value1;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public int Value2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay cool, I was unsure if I was doing Example one as I came up with something similar but now I see that it is correct. Pretty much example 1 and 3 are what I wanting. Can't do example 3 though as not using net 7 but that seems to make it very clean. I guess since it is happen after that is what vm.Value1 actually has the right value.

Comment: Razor compiler builds out something similar to example 1 for all of them.  For 3 it just sets the value then calls the after method.